# Postgres: Query to loop over another subquery query

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I hope this is not a duplicate question, I tried searching this for over an hour but couldn't find anything.

I am using postgres 9.5 and while working on event orchestration process and with following event table structure. I am trying to write query will give list of successors for every event id.

```
event_id | event_name | predecessor_list

01       | eventA          | []
02       | eventB          | [01]
03       | eventC          | [01]
04       | eventD          | [01, 02]
05       | eventE          | [01, 03, 04]
```

I tried using subquery,

```
select event_id from event_table et where (select event_id from event_table) = ANY (predecessor_list)
```

but got following exception

> `ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

Output that I am expecting is;

```
event_id | successors
01 | [02, 03, 04, 05]
02 | [04]
03 | [05]
04 | [05]
05 | []
```

I am quite new to postgres and tried joins too, but it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I would start by eliminating columns that contain multiple values. Use the unnest function to do this and then you will have a proper relational structure that will be much easier to query

Answer (score 1):

I drew out a tree using your example to better understand the problem.  A few things (assuming I did it properly) revealed by the tree are:-

A) In events 04 and 05 you don't need to store event 01, because in the case of 04: 02 is a parent of 04, and 01 is a parent of 02, so implicitly this info is captured.  Same thing with event 05.

B) I'm not sure whether what you are expecting as output matches the tree structure.  You say you are expecting

```
event_id | successors 
02 | [04]
```

But as 05 is a child of 04 and therefore takes place after 04 should this read like so?

```
event_id | successors
02 | [04] [05]
```

I'm doubtful that what you are trying to achieve is actually possible in SQL (with the given model). I've worked as an oracle DBA for longer than I should have and I would probably say to my clients don't do it like this - and spend some time with them to get a better understanding of the business case for the model or find a model which fits the requirement better.  But as I'm new to Postgresql maybe I don't have enough knowledge to say for sure whether it is possible (or not) in Postgresql. I'll see what I can find.

Having said all that a bit later on, I managed to find a way

Version check:

```
select version();
| version |
| :--------|
| PostgreSQL 9.5.25 on x86\_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 11.2.1\_git20220219) 11.2.1 20220219, 64-bit |
```

Create table and data...

```
CREATE TABLE event (
  event_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  event_name VARCHAR(100),
  predecessor_list integer[]
);

INSERT INTO event(event_id, event_name, predecessor_list) values (1, 'eventA',null);
INSERT INTO event(event_id, event_name, predecessor_list) values (2, 'eventB','{1}');     
INSERT INTO event(event_id, event_name, predecessor_list) values (3, 'eventC','{1}');     
INSERT INTO event(event_id, event_name, predecessor_list) values (4, 'eventD','{1,2}');     
INSERT INTO event(event_id, event_name, predecessor_list) values (5, 'eventE','{1,3,4}');
```

Query to pull out events with their successors

```
select 
  E1.event_id,
  (
  ARRAY(select E2.event_id 
  from event E2 
  where E1.event_id = ANY (E2.predecessor_list)
  ))
from 
  event E1 
;
```

The results:

```
| event_id | array |
| ---------:|:------|
| 1 | {2,3,4,5} |
| 2 | {4} |
| 3 | {5} |
| 4 | {5} |
| 5 | {} |
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @churcht for the reponse
this is the existing event chain we have and I need to work on that :) 

for point A - we do have some transitive dependencies in here, but 05 directly depends on 01 also, it doesn't have to follow the dependencies check from 05->04->02->01 before executing ( as per the use case )

for point B
we are not considering the transitive dependencies, only directs.
so, when event 02 is invoked, after it's execution, it will invoke 04 and not 05  

But thanks for the query, it worked.